# Lenovo Legion 5 (15ACH6) running Ubuntu 22.04 - Goes to Lock Screen when attempting to Suspend

Tags: nvidia, suspend, lenovo, lock-screen, nouveau

I'm using a Lenovo Legion 5 (15ACH6) running Ubuntu 22.04, and I'm looking to have the Suspend mode working preoperly. When I try to suspend the notebook it goes straight into the Lock Screen, which disappears after sometime and enters a black screen, however I know its still not suspended as the power light is on and steady, plus if I can still SSH into the machine.  This should not be the case as in Windows when you enter suspend mode, the power light blinks and you are unable to remote login into the machine.

I have played around with all the display drivers from Nvidia and nouveau, however switching these drivers did not do anything.

Please advise what I should do next.